# Distribution of Digits of Binary Expansion of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

In considering the binary expansion of prime numbers, I'm interesting in the skew of digits towards 0 or 1.

I searched through other questions and arrived at:
[Last digits of primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/last-digits-of-primes)

I just want to confirm my suspicion that if I exclude the most significant binary digit and the 3 least significant binary digits (in avoidance of issues from 2 and 5), and if i consider each binary position independently, the distribution across primes should tend to a 50/50 balance of 0s and 1s?

Should this follow as well for distinct semiprimes?

Anything other impacts (e.g. 3, 7, ...)?

Comment: What is the issue with $5$ that you are trying to avoid?  What do the last $3$ bits have to do with it?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @saulpatz the li ked question excluded 2 and 5.

Comment: The linked question was about decimal digits.  That's why $5$ is special.  But that's irrelevant for binary digits.

Comment: My intuition led me to believe that since 5 and its multiples were excluded from being represented within a binary expansion, it would have an impact in a similar but lesser way that 2 has an impact (that the least significant digit is never 0).  What I'm gathering is that my intuition was wrong.  What else is new? :-) I will look into understanding the references that have been provided.  Thanks.

Comment: Would it be correct to say then that you're talking about primes in octal? If so, https://oeis.org/A004682 would be quite relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last binary digit is, of course, $1$ except for the prime $2$.  Every other binary digit, including the second-last and third-last, should be (asymptotically) equally likely to be $0$ or $1$, because of (the strong form of) [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on primes in arithmetic progressions: asymptotically, for any fixed $m$, the primes are evenly distributed among the odd congruence classes mod $2^m$.

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a look at your reference.  In reviewing the source of my error, looks like I assumed that 5 and its multiples would have an impact in biasing the 3 least significant digits.  In looking at the first 8 multiples of 5, all combinations of 0s and 1s are reflected in those 3 digits.  I gather this is what I missed on my initial review.